# Conditionally calculate duration from multiple rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I have a table `session_logs` in PostgreSQL 10.5 with the following entries:

```
id recorded_at          powered  camera_blocked
----------------------------------------------------
1  2019-06-26 13:40:00  true     false
2  2019-06-26 13:45:00  false    false
3  2019-06-26 13:50:00  false    true
4  2019-06-26 13:55:00  false    false
5  2019-06-26 14:00:00  true     false
6  2019-06-26 14:05:00  true     false
```

And I want to write a query that will give me the following results

```
started_at           ended_at            power_dur battery_dur camera_blocked_dur
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2019-06-26 13:40:00 2019-06-26 13:55:00  10        15          5
```

(where duration (dur) is in minutes)

How do I go about writing a query that can correctly sum these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lead()` and conditional aggregation

```
select min(recorded_at), max(recorded_at),
       sum(next_recorded_at - recorded_at) filter (where powered),
       sum(next_recorded_at - recorded_at) filter (where camera_blocked)
from (select t.*,
             lead(recorded_at) over (order by recorded_at) as next_recorded_at
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: I had originally ran this in an online fiddle that was psql 9.3, but re-ran in 10 and it works as expected. thank you so much!

Comment: For anyone wanting to see/use a db-fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7oC2w76QKuS5R4BapiqExW/0

Comment: @gordon_linoff if I add a field `session_id` and want to group results by that, how do I still correctly calculate the lead? When I group by with multiple sessions, I get the wrong totals.

Comment: @theartofbeing . . . If `group by session_id` doesn't answer your question, then you should ask a *new* question.